# where to find document about dpkg/deb authentication

Tags: apt, dpkg, authentication

I am looking for documents about how to work the authentication system on debian packages.
For example I have found that

```
dpkg --verify pkg
```

it verifies the package with an hash. But I am looking how to authenticate a package with the repository public key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may contain what you are looking for  (the *debian* source is provided too)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SecureApt

Much packaging doco can be found at http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/